# how to take first 3 character from a string using PHP

Tags: mysql

I need to take only three characters from the string stored in MYSQL and output must be the first 3 character and the login date of customer

I am beginner kindly help me to code in PHP.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr, then also pull the date column. Not really a PHP question unless that's the part you are having issues with; if so add the relevant PHP.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT LEFT(string , 3) , logindate FROM tbl;
```

Hope this will help you.